# Rule of uploading picture on social media

Tags: halal-haram, quran, hadith

Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu

I want to ask whether it's halal or Haram to upload personal picture on social, either male or female

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waallaikum sallam waramatullahi wabarakatuhu

If it comes to the matter of uploading picture on social media, is either Haram or halal
Because is not stated in any verse of the Qur'an and Hadith that is forbidden but we come to think of it, our beloved prophet said
is narrated on the authority of Amirul Mu’minin, Abu Hafs ‘Umar bin al-Khattab, radiyallahu ‘anhu, who said: I heard the Messenger of Allah, sallallahu ‘alayhi wasallam, say:
“Actions are (judged) by motives (niyyah), so each man will have what he intended. Thus, he whose migration (hijrah) was to Allah and His Messenger, his migration is to Allah and His Messenger; but he whose migration was for some worldly thing he might gain, or for a wife he might marry, his migration is to that for which he migrated.”
[Al-Bukhari & Muslim]

So base on this Hadith the action of uploading a picture should be base on the intention of that person, if it's done for a genuine purpose than is not Haram but if is not for a genuine purpose then is Haram

But for a female, she must put on there her hijjab on the picture

Jazakumul llahu khayran